# Splitting a list with one item

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

IPython and python 3.4 have 'import re' in the namespace.

Trying to remove the tag `<LOCATION>` from this list called 'location'.

```
location =  ['<LOCATION>12345 Restaurant Ave']
```

and store it into another list, in this case 'final_location'.

When I type:

```
final_location = re.sub(r'<LOCATION>', '', location)
```

I receive the error
    TypeError: expected string or buffer

help is appreciated, either with re or some other way as I'll have many of these lists and need to scrub/remove certain character patterns on some text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re` works on strings - you should apply it to the element in the list, not the list itself. E.g.:

```
final_location = [re.sub(r'<LOCATION>', '', location[0])]
```

Or, in a more general fashion, if you can't assume the list has a single element:

```
final_location = [re.sub(r'<LOCATION>', '', l) for l in location]
```